# Performance issues using LocalValidatorFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, performance, validation, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to understand why my program's execution time is so long. The aim of my program is to import CSV data, and validate it line by line.

It appears that 90% of my execution time is spent for the validation of data.
This is my validation function :

```
public static <T> HashSet<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(Validator validator, T resource, Class<?>... groups) {
    return (HashSet<ConstraintViolation<T>>) validator.validate(resource, groups);
}
```

And the validator I use is LocalValidatorFactoryBean, imported in Spring like this :

```
<bean id="validator" name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

I noticed that the validation was taking more and more time at every iteration... for example, if I've got 1000 **similar lines** on my CSV file, the first will be validated in ~55ms, and the last in ~900ms.

I have no idea how to explain this non-linear execution time, and how to improve it : did I do any mistake ? Should I configure my bean differently ? Should I use an other validator (which one?) ?

Thanks for you time :)

Comment: What are you validating. What is `T resource` are you sure it is validation that takes so long? If you are using JPA it might be that validation is done also (and that might increase with the number of entities in yuor first level cache).

Comment: I'm validating the data. For instance, I check if the first column is a number, the second is a String between 5 and 255 characters and follow some other rules, ect... (The CVS file can easily have 100 columns for the data I have to deal with, and each columns can have 1-5 rules).
By the way, I am sure that my validate function takes almost all the time (~90%).
And yes, I'm using JPA Hibernate.

Comment: Well check your validation logic, also as mentioned hibernate also uses validation so if that is also in the mix you micht even have duplicate validation and if changes occur get a performance hit for dirty checking (basically for each select that is done). This increases quite linear with each object added to the first level cache. But currently it is hard to tell without seeing code, configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using a `LinkedList`? This could explain the growing time, assuming there are many columns and the access to the fields does not cache the row.

Try to replace the validation by some no-op and watch if the times change. Or simply debug into a call (or let it throw and look at the stacktrace) to see what funny things happen.